# fonts.googleapis is showing different CSS files based on the browser type

Tags: html, css

insdie my CSS files i am referencing fonts suc as :-

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular&amp;subset=latin
```

But now i need to download these CSS and add them to my host, instead of downloading them from google. but the problem i am facing is that when i try to download the related CSS files by access the above link from my IE it downlaod the following :-

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v4/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciFQlYEbsez9cZjKsNMjLOwM.eot);
  src: local('Droid Sans'), local('DroidSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v4/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciFQlYEbsez9cZjKsNMjLOwM.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v4/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciBsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
}
```

While on firefox it shows  the following :-

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Droid Sans'), local('DroidSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v4/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciBsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
}
```

So i got lost on which url() i should download ? the woff or the tff ?? or both ?

**EDIT**

I have replaced this

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Ubuntu);
```

with

```
/*@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Ubuntu);*/

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('~/Content/fonts/8gO-GQO6h3meAtqRrd890A.eot');
  src: local('Karla'), local('Karla-Regular'), url('~/Content/fonts/8gO-GQO6h3meAtqRrd890A.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('~/Content/fonts/azR40LUJrT4HaWK28zHmVA.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('~/Content/fonts/_tMhxyW6i8lbI7YsUdFlGA.eot');
  src: local('Ubuntu'), url('~/Content/fonts/_tMhxyW6i8lbI7YsUdFlGA.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('~/Content/fonts/_xyN3apAT_yRRDeqB3sPRg.woff') format('woff');
}
```

But the fonts effect did not work ? although when using the `@import` i can see the fonts effect, while when i reference them locally they stopped working.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to download them? Unless you're hosting a local website (e.g. an intranet), doesn't it make more sense to get them from Google?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin , yes exactly i am working on a Intranet local website, and sometime users might access the intranet without having access to the internet..

Comment: Does the browser try to load the font?

Comment: @box86rowh not sure how i can check this , can u advice ?

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: What's with the '~/' at the start of your SRC for these fonts? If you're just doing this locally, then refer to the font files relative to where your CSS file is.

Answer (score 2):

If you do need to use the fonts locally (rather than linking to Google's hosted versions), then they provide a download link on each font's page (in the top right)<sup>1</sup>.

[image: download link screenshot]

The download link offers the option to 'Download the font families in your Collection as a .zip file'. If you do that, you'll get all the different versions (.ttf/.eot etc) that are needed for cross-browser @font-face support<sup>2</sup>.

1. You should have a good reason for doing so however: linking to the hosted version is simpler, and you'll automatically be using the latest version of each font.
2. Different browsers require different formats (the multiple `src`'s in your CSS). Again though, if you're not familiar with what's required just stick with linking to Google's hosted files.

Comment: the reason i need to reference them locally, is that i am working on an intranet local website. but can you check my edit please.as i try to reference them locally but the fonts did not load well.